# Should I use a thumbdrive I got on a conference in China?

Tags: usb-drive

I (from EU) recently attended a scientific conference in China. As part of the goodies there is a decent looking thumbdrive which has the conference logo printed on it. It seems to be in original packaging, so I guess somebody ordered them to be made with the logo from the manufacturer directly.

I am a bit wary about getting thumbdrives that I did not ask for. For instance there was the RSA conference where the vendor screwed up loading the conference material onto the drive and and there was malware on it was well. Additionally I have no feeling on whether intelligence services use this opportunity to get a bridgehead into various university networks.

As I do not need a thumbdrive, I will likely just not use it myself. But is that overly paranoid? Should I just gift it to somebody else?

Comment: With the only details to work with being "USB drive" and "China", the most we can do is speculate. I wouldn't use it, though. Hand it to a forensic researcher to play with it and see what hidden surprises it might hold.

Answer (score 3):

This is primarily an opinion based question so there's a good chance it'll be locked - but I'll give my two cents ahead of whatever that verdict ends up being.

---

The general rule of thumb is: **if you are suspicious - don't use it**; and if that's why you're not using it, don't just give it to someone else for them to use. My recommendation would be to see if there is somewhere near you that recycles electronics, or if you happen to know any security minded person that *wants* to take a look at it for fun you could give it to them and be up front about its origins.

Formatting the drive from a controlled machine will get rid of a most of your run-of-the-mill malware - but for USB devices specifically, the main issues arise from the firmware. Your computer doesn't communicate directly with the flash memory on the stick - it communicates with the controller first. If it's a cheap device, chances are it likely has cheap/malformed protocols handling things under the hood - and then of course the worst case scenario is that they've been maliciously configured. It's fascinating what can go wrong with USB (any USB, not just the flash drives) so I highly recommend doing some googling just to see - if you're interested.

As an example: you can get all kinds of different firmware on a USB stick - say, you plug it in and part of it has been designed to behave like a keyboard, which your computer will recognize as a keyboard and automatically install - only, this false-keyboard also has keybinds it has been programmed to run, which - given the amount of keyboard shortcuts and available commands, and depending on the level of access the user of the keyboard has - can do just about anything.

Treat your device's physical security just as you would when configuring a firewall - deny everything that you are not explicitly OK with.

Answer (score -3):

You are a little too paranoid. I got such thumb drives practically from any big tech conference I've been at in any given country.

That included companies like MS, Cisco, Veeam, Adobe, IBM, many large telecom companies.

Basically, the purpose of the drive is for participants to get all presentations material in an electronic format while offering them something useful at the same time.

On the drives, I usually found presentations from each company attending the conference.

They are usually of low to junk quality USB 2.0 drives, which isn't worth much but they serve the purpose of spreading the presentations.

Many of them I have deeply checked, including comparing the firmware to one from the original manufacturer.

Comment: Being to paranoid is related to what kind of target he is. If he's Joe Schmoe, it developer for some small website, maybe its too much. But if he's Joe Brow the top sysadmin for a big financial company then maybe its paranoid enough.

Comment: We usually talk in general. Of course, a targeted thing is something else, but can be countered with ease: if you think you're a target for such an action just switch the drive with someone else's.

Comment: Your only analysis is that you get them all the time, therefore they pose little risk? It's not from a vendor, but the conference itself. Being a scientific conference, it is in the best interest of the country if they can get access to research on attendee's machines back home. Dispersing out USBs is a well-known tactic when the area is a parking lot. How much more valuable would the exercise be if you handed it to a vetted person of value (scientist at an international conference)?

Comment: As someone who protects multiple scientific research communities, I would not be so cavalier with the risk assessment. Researchers are targetted, and a breach's impact tends to reach into the $1000's to start. We are not talking about PII or credit card details here. The data has immediate commercial value at scale.

Comment: No, the analysis is is digging into their Firmware. They were all fine.